# Can I always change the order of integration and limits?

Tags: integration, limits

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, is there any case when this equivalence is not valid?

$$\int \lim_{x\to c}f(x) dc = \lim_{x\to c}\int f(x)dx$$

---

My teacher did this in one of the classes, while saying something along the lines of "(...) and we can do this because $f(x)$ is well-behaved...". It immediately got me thinking: how "badly behaved" a function must be for this to be voided?

Comment: In the right hand side, you take the limit with respect to $x$ of something that does not depend on $x$. And in the left-hand side, after taking the limit, you integrate a constant. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Both the right and left hand side of this equation do not make any sence, you cannot use $x$ in the limit *and* as an integration variable.

Comment: that was a mistake, the integral should be indefinite..

Comment: So you want to say $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = \lim_{x \to c} F(x)$ where $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f$? As it is now, your equation sill makes no sense because, the LHS is dependent on $x$ while the RHS is just a constant.

Comment: Actually I wanted to say: $\int \lim_{x-\to c} f(x) dx= \lim_{x\to c}F(x)$. I edited the question, I hope now it's clearer

Comment: The left hand side is still the integral of a constant, since $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ does not depend on $x$.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Give me one sec and I'll check the lecture notes.

Comment: Is it possible you meant something like $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^{b} f_{n} = \int_{a}^{b} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_{n}$ or $\lim\limits_{x \to c} \int_{a}^{b} f(x, y)\, dy = \int_{a}^{b} \lim\limits_{x \to c} f(x, y)\, dy$?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, no, it was about limits tending to a finite number indeed.

Comment: Ok, I believe that the question makes more sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many conditions which can be used to show that you can exchange limits and integrals, most of them boil down to Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem, or the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

As for when it can fail, there are basically two ways this can happen: (1) the mass of the function runs away to $\infty$, or (2) the mass of the function accumulates around some point.

The two standard examples of these are:

(1) Take $f_n(x) = 1_{[n,n+1]}(x)$, i.e. $f_n(x)=1$ if $x \in [n,n+1]$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ otherwise. Clearly $f_n(x) \to 0$ for all $x$, but $\int f_n(x)\,dx = 1 \neq 0 =\int 0\,dx$. In this case the mass "ran away" to infinity.

(2) Take $f_n(x) = n 1_{(0,1/n]}$, i.e. $f_n(x) = n$ if $x \in (0,1/n]$ and $f_n(x)=0$ otherwise. Clearly $f_n(x) \to 0$ for all $x$, but $\int f_n(x)\,dx= n\cdot \frac{1}{n} = 1 \neq 0 = \int 0 \,dx$. In this case the mass accumulates around 0.

Comment: Your second paragraph, made rigorous, is the Vitali Convergence Theorem, which is the most general statement of this type (in the sense that its hypotheses are necessary and sufficient).